# Rules regarding the name of G-od in the website?

Tags: discussion, editing

I'm a bit shocked to see how The Name is written without any "changes" in it and how the vocalization is freely unveiled.

> Since it's completely forbidden to pronounce or use in vain, I would like to know
>   why there aren't any rules or moderators' surveillance regarding it in
>   this website (I checked the FAQ, and didn't find anything)?

How come we jump on little things like tags and not on this?
I'm sure a lot of thinking has been put in this and decisions have been made and I would like to understand. (Maybe this should be in the meta website, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: this does seem to be a meta-question, and one which begs http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/hashems-name-on-device

Comment: your link doesn't supply any reference and is not located in the meta site...

Comment: I've migrated this to our Meta site, as it primarily asks about site policy.

Comment: feel free to look through all the referenced questions via http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10777/what-are-the-practical-limits-of-shaimos-in-the-common-era and see that the issue of digital presentation vis-a-vis halacha has been explored. the meta part is beyond me. i'm a n00b

Comment: For some Meta discussion see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/32/759

Comment: Are you asking about "God" vs "G-d" or about other transliterations such as "Elohim"?

Comment: Speaking of "little things like tags", [meta-tag:halacha] has hitherto been used for questions about main-site halacha-related questions, not for questions (like this one) that are themselves halacha-related. So I'm detagging this.

Comment: @DoubleAA ... or straight-up Hebrew spellings?

Comment: Mainly about the Hebrew name, I'm surprised how people takes precautions to write "G-d" or else but fully write the true name or the true pronunciation w/o any problem... As I'm an Israeli and religious those English Transliterations are much more meaningful than a simple word of 3 letters without any real signifaction

Comment: Sorry you've been displeased by my spellings mistakes, I rushed in asking a question that I thought crucial as it directly concerns the firsts of the ten commandments (for me at least)

Comment: @danie7LT I think it is a little presumptuous of you to say that the name "God" has no significance when I can't think of any reason it wouldn't work to fulfill the Biblical command of reciting the Shema when done so in English.

Comment: G-od isn't the name of HaShem, G-od as D-ieu D-eus etc are words in foreign languages to express the idea of G-od nothing "presumptuous"

Comment: @danie7LT And because they are in foreign languages they are meaningless? See for instance Igrot Moshe OC 4:40 where he rules that blessings recited unnecessarily in foreign languages are full-fledged brachot levatallah. Turns out they are quite meaningful indeed even though they aren't in Hebrew.

Comment: @Double AA Let me get things right for you. I pray in French and hear Portuguese prayers every day since I was born in France and my wife is Brazilian but I live in Israel for a long time now. Praying in french doesn't "disturb" anything of the content/demands but when I write D-ieu or say it in french I don't brake any law regarding the respect of the name of god which I do if I was using the real name instead

Comment: @danie7LT Actually, many poskim disagree with what you just said. I'm not going to continue arguing here with you, but I encourage you to ask on the main site for more discussion.

Comment: @double AA I did, and as nicely as I could, you moved my post here, some joked about my mistakes in English, got a -3 and finally got an answer in a comment. and I don't get what you meant in your comment above? Can you give some clues please?

Comment: @danie7LT, welcome to meta and a belated welcome to Mi Yodeya.  You raised the validity of saying translations of the divine name in other languages; I encourage you to ask that on the main site if you're interested in learning more on that topic.

Comment: @danie7LT Yes, I'm apologize if I sound antagonistic, but your question was written with somewhat of an accusatory tone. As noted above, this question is about Mi Yodeya's policy regarding God's name, and as such was moved here. If you want to know about the halachik status of different translations/transliterations in general, then you should ask that on the main site for more discussion.

Comment: Also, realize that people were not downvoting you because of spelling mistakes, see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thank you for your greetings, you wrote "You raised the validity of saying translations of the divine name in other languages;" and I understand, I guess it comes from "without any real signification" I wrote many comments above. I'm sorry but I will use your comment to re-center the subject which was ***the paradoxical fact that people write the name of G-od with great precautions in English*** (as it should be as a mark of respect) ***but when it comes to Hebrew just write it down in plain black & white letters w/o any mark of consideration***.

Comment: By seeing those letters displayed as-is and talked about as "Harry talk about Sally" I got shocked and reacted by asking a question where my "touchiness" in this subject could be felt - sorry, I should have breathe deeper - Now regarding the validity of prayers in foreign languages, this subject got out in the comment only (no mention of it in the question).

Comment: As I mentioned elsewhere prayers around me are in many different languages but naming G-od in English or French or Portuguese or any languages is completely different as naming G-od in Hebrew and that's what I wanted to say with "without any real signification". Again sorry I used your comment for that :) Chabbat Chalom LeKulam

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm sure of that, but you realize that with a -3 what's the point of asking again on this subject for me, I preferred to close this subject here as I made a recap of what was my intentions, I got an explanation about the policy of the website regarding it and I will see how I will deal with it later. Chabbat Chalom

Comment: @danie7LT, I'm sorry if my comments have added to the confusion.  Your question was about writing, and in the discussion a couple tangents came up, one about *speaking* as distinct from writing, and one about speaking name-equivalents in other languages and whether they "count".  I was just suggesting that these would be fine topics for their own questions on Mi Yodeya, independent of the written-transliteration question or moderation policy.  For that matter, a question about writing "elokim" versus the actual transliteration would also be welcome on the main site.

Comment: @danie7LT, I'm also sorry that your participation got off to a rocky start, and I do hope you'll continue to ask and answer questions.  This got moved to meta because it asked about moderator policy, not because you asked about written forms.  And on meta voting means something different; it signals agreement/disagreement and does not affect reputation.  If you don't want to ask some of these related questions on main then I might because now I'm curious, but you should have first crack at them.  I think they'll get up-votes.

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4226

Answer (score 2):

Words like "God" are not the Name; they are translations.  Nonetheless, some people write "G-d" (or "Hashem") anyway and those same people also write "Elokim" etc.

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/hashems-name-on-device) addresses issues about divine names in Hebrew on digital devices.  If using a Hebrew name on a computer does not pose a halachic problem, then it seems even less likely that a transliteration of one would.

Policing the site to remove/transform names anyway would always be imperfect, so it would still be the reader's responsibility to check a particular page before printing it out.  Since printing pages from Mi Yodeya is probably infrequent, that seems an acceptable approach.

Comment: I think he was asking (based on [his comment](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/rules-regarding-the-name-of-g-od-in-the-website#comment3803_1353)) that he was asking why people write "G-d" (instead of "God") but then write "Elohim" instead of "Elokim"

Comment: @ba, oh I see now.  (His comment arrived while I was typing and I didn't see it.  Will update.)

Comment: Thank you for editing my mistakes in my post. Thank you for your kind answer Monica Cellio and @ba you're right that's a part of what I meant

Comment: +1 Moreover most poskim agree that reciting God's name properly while learning Torah is not forbidden Biblicaly or Rabbinicaly, although some (particularly Ashkenazim) have a custom to avoid doing so anyway. So Mi Yodeya would not adopt a policy which would seem to rule on this matter, but we would let everyone choose what to write for themselves.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's what I was asking in the first in my post, the reasonning behind the liberty given to anybody to write the name of G-od the way he wants- thank you for that

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13386/saying-hashems-name-when-studying