# What's the policy regarding the use of (the Jewish) god's name on the site?

Tags: discussion, offensive-content

I'm a Hebrew speaker, but am not an observant Jew, hence I tend to use the Jewish god's name:

1. when referring to him;
2. when quoting text containing his name.

What's the policy on using the express name here on the site, in each of these two contexts?

In [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1211/4996) it says that

> A digital representation of Hashem's name, whether it is His unique name or others, does not constitute writing. Consequently there is no issue of erasing it.

but that's unsourced ("I asked my Rabbi and he told me so") and I'm not soure how the community here feels about that.

**Notes:**

- [Rules regarding the name of G-od in the website?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/rules-regarding-the-name-of-g-od-in-the-website) - somewhat related mostly about the English word "God".

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, there is currently no rule on Mi Yodeya regarding the use of holy names. There are many posts that include instances of the Tetragrammaton, copy/pasted from online Tanachs, and there are many posts in which holy names are deliberately obscured. It's up to the reader (and even more so, anyone who prints out content from here) to take appropriate care.

When we curate and format Mi Yodeya content for printing in [Mi Yodeya Publications](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications), we do try to make sure to obscure all instances of official Holy Names in Hebrew.

This answer describes the state of site policy, as I understand it. I don't think it would be inappropriate for other answers to advocate for what their authors think our policy *ought to be*.